# Shifted hyperlink with includestandalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, positioning, standalone

I have a problem with includestandalone and a tikz-grafic with a hyperref.

My MWE:
I define a image as picture.tex:

```
%Save as picture.tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (problem) {Problem};
\node (ask) [below=of problem] {Ask at \url{http://www.stackexchange.com}};
\node (solution) [below=of ask] {Solution};
\draw[->] (problem) -- (ask) -- (solution);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The picture looks fine, the link is correct.

Now I include the picture with `includestandalone` in my main document:

```
\documentclass[paper=a6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,standalone}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\includestandalone{picture}
\end{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The picture looks ok, but the hyperlink is moved to the bottom:
[image]

Some additional information:

- The a6-option is only used to get a smaller screenshot. It has no influence on the problem.
- The red arrow in the screenshot is not part of the document, it should only show the problem.
- If I use `\input` instead `\includestandalone` the link is correct. But this is not the solution I need. My original picture is large and I scale it with `\includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{picture}`.
- Up to now I use `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` to make the wrong link invisible.

My question:
How can I get the correct position of my hyperlink in an included tikz-picture?

---

In meantime I updated to TeXLive 2013 and the error still exists.

My listfile-result:

```
 *File List*
scrartcl.cls    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2012/04/04 v3.10b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
standalone.sty    2012/09/15 v1.1b Package to include TeX sub-files with preambles
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
currfile.sty    2013/02/01 v0.7b Provides the file path elements of the current input file
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
filehook-scrlfile.sty    2011/01/03 v0.1 filehook patch for scrlfile package
gincltex.sty    2011/09/04 v0.3 Include external LaTeX files like graphics
svn-prov.sty    2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
adjustbox.sty    2012/05/21 v1.0 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)
 adjcalc.sty    2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
trimclip.sty    2012/05/16 v1.0 Trim and clip general TeX material
collectbox.sty    2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
tc-pdftex.def    2012/05/13 v1.0 Clipping driver for pdftex
ifoddpage.sty    2011/09/13 v1.0 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
filemod-expmin.sty    2011/09/19 v1.2 Get and compare file modification times (expandable; minimal)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
myarticle.out
myarticle.out
 picture.tex    Graphic file (type tex)
 picture.tex    Graphic file (type tex)
 ***********
```

I tested my result with Acrobat Reader and Sumatra (both on windows).

Any idea?

Comment: I am getting it alright. May be you need an update for your packages.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks. Good to know, that it works correct. I will check it this evening with another PC and compare the package versions.

Comment: I checked again with same result, but also with the same versions (TeXlive 2012 with last updates). I will check again, when I updated to TeXlive 2013.

Comment: The same here. It works.

Comment: With `pdflatex`, it works. Your bug appears with `lualatex`!

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, indeed. Thanks! I will check the luatex bug tracker for this effect and perhaps report the problem if I find nothing.

Comment: Sounds similar like [Hyperlinks wrongly placed if resized](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=840) @PaulGaborit You may make an answer of it, so I can accept it and the question can be 'closed'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug of current version of `luatex`: [Hyperlinks wrongly placed if resized](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=840).